# Copy cannot be started due to gateway was offline, how to run my pipelines?

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory

We have SSIS packages running on a server with sql server agent. However, we want to move this job to a cloud solution. One solution is to use a powershell script, but we also tried to replace SSIS with Azure Data Factory.

However, as stated above, the gateway requires my computer to be online and can't be installed on a domain controller (server). Does this mean that data factory cannot be used to fill our database at night (when the pc's are shutdown) and is therefore not a good replacement for SSIS?

Are there any other solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Data Gateway can be installed on any computer in your network that has access to the SQL Server. Obviously both the gateway and the SQL server need to be up at the time the activity runs.